# hide/show actionbar tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

Upon install, my app would show only 1 tab, hence I want to hide the tab row.

When user login/signup, additional tabs would show up.

I create tabs(fragments) in onCreate().

```
   @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

        if(logged_in()){
            m_actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            m_actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(this.m_previousTabIndex);
        }
        else
            m_actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

        return;
    }
```

I don't see the tabs.. that's good.
But I don't see the first tab's contents either. I don't see nothing but actionBar in screen.
How do I fix this to show the first tab's contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/samples) samples to see how they work.